# Iterate through fixtures in a template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using `ember-cli` and `Ember v1.13.0-beta.1` and I have the following model, route and template.

**models/products.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Product = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  ...
});

Product.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Title',
      ...
    }
  ]
});

export default Product;
```

**routes/products.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.all('product');
  }
});
```

**templates/products**

```
{{#each product in model}}
  {{product.title}}
{{/each}}
```

Also in **app/js** I have `App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;`

When I use a simple Array in the route, then it renders fine in the template but ever since I switched to fixtures, it stopped doing so.

When I log `this.store.all('product')` it seems to return the right object.

Also, not sure if it's relevant but from the beginning I cannot do

```
{{#each}}
  {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

I have to always reference the model like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixtures in ember-cli applications work differently.

> If you’re used to using fixtures to get test data into your app during
>   development, you won’t be able to create fixture data like you’re used
>   to doing (i.e. as specified in the guides). This is because the models
>   in your Ember CLI app (like all other objects) aren’t attached to the
>   global namespace.

To create a mock for a products API endpoint, use

`ember g http-mock products`

Your `app/adapters/application.js` should be

```
 // adapters/application.js
 import DS from "ember-data";

 export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
```

See http://www.ember-cli.com/#mocks-and-fixtures

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct because as it has provided most of the answer and pointed me to the right direction to solve the above issue. Can you please add to your answer that with ember-cli fixtures do not work as documented in ember docs but you need to create a mock `ember g http-mock product`. That's the part missing from your answer :) Thanks!